# GIMP plugin to change ticket number and export image automatically

Tags: gimp

I have designed a ticket which includes a sequential ticket number (001,002,003...500) and now I have to export each and every ticket number as a separate PNG image.

This is a lot of manual work and I'm asking if there is a plugin or script that I can use to do this automatically - something I can give the text layer to change incrementally then export the image.

**EDIT**

This is my ticket.
The ticket number is at the left side corner - 2014/001 -> 2014/500
Image size: 2858px by 1000px
The ticket number font is [Dirt2 SoulStalker](http://www.dafont.com/dirt2-soulstalker.font)

[image]

Comment: I think it can be done.  what is the size of your ticket image and where does the number need to appear?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Edited...

Comment: @JacobVlijm Maybe [this](http://www.gimptalk.com/index.php?/topic/47800-fast-way-to-create-hundreds-of-sequentially-numbered-buttons/) can shed some light

Comment: Nice ticket! What I have in mind is automatically adding an extra layer (with Imagemagick) with a transparant background. The numbering is the easy part. I did some tests, seems to work nicely, but the font seems pretty essential in your case, Ah I see you added it. ...And it is a comercial one.

Comment: Thanks. The font is essential to prevent copy-cats (though it's all over the internet now) ;-)

Comment: Is this the original size (2858x1000)?

Comment: Yah. 20cms by 7cms (then scaled down)

Comment: It should work now, see the answer below. The script adds the number in a range from 0 to 500 (or another range), creating separate files called "005_ticket.png" and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it working.

[image]

The procedure is that you put the background image (named "background.png", the ticket without the number, but *with* `2014/`) in a folder, together with the script below. Then, if you run the script (after editing the three lines in the head section):

- The script produces numbers from `001` to `500` (but it can be any number you define in the head section)
  Subsequently , using `imagemagick`:
- the script creates (number by number) separate layers (files) with the number in the right position
- it copies the background layer + number layers into a new file, saved in the same folder, for each number.
- the script then removes the (temporary) additional layers

[image]

#### Notes

- You may have to install `imagemagick`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install imagemagick
  ```
- I used [this free version](http://www.1001freefonts.com/dirt2_soulstalker.font) of the font. It turned out that in the script, I had to set the absolute path to the font for it to work. I just copied it to `~/.fonts` and used that path. In the head section of the script, set yours.

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os

curr_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#---
number_of_tickets = 5
bg_file = curr_path+"/"+"background.png"
font = '/home/jacob/.fonts/dirt2 soulstalker.otf'
#---

def command(string, layer, position):
    return "convert -size 2858x1000 xc:None -fill black -font "+'"'+font+'"'+\
           " -stroke None -fill white -pointsize 123 -style Normal -gravity west -draw "+\
           position+"'"+string+"'"+'" '+layer

def print_tofile(string, number):
    print("creating file "+number+"."*3)
    layer_1 = curr_path+"/"+number+"_a.png"
    layer_2 = curr_path+"/"+number+"_b.png"
    cmd_1 = command(string, layer_1, '"text 497,-420 ')
    cmd_2 = command(string, layer_2, '"text 1035,-420 ')
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd_1])
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd_2])
    cmd_3 = "convert "+bg_file+" "+layer_1+" "+layer_2+\
            " -background None -layers merge "+curr_path+"/"+number+"_ticket.png"
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd_3])
    os.remove(layer_1)
    os.remove(layer_2)
    print("done")

ns = [str(n) for n in range(number_of_tickets+1)][1:]

for item in ns:
    number = str(int(3-len(item))*"0")+item
    string = number
    print_tofile(string, number)
```

#### How to use

Copy it into an empty file, in th head section of the script, set:

- the number of tickets
- the (absolute) path to the font
- the name of the background image (ticket without numbers) if you want to change it

and save it as `numbering.py`, together with your background image (2858px by 1000px), named `background.png` in one and the same folder.

Run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py
```

Comment: I did them manually since they were needed urgently. Will give it a try though.