# ImageMagick "convert" command cannot use fonts!

Tags: fonts, imagemagick, convert-command

```
convert -size 300x50 xc:none -font Arial -pointsize 20 -gravity center -draw "fill white text 1,1 \"$1\" text 0,0 \"$1\" fill black text -1,-1 \"$1\"" $WATERMARK_FILE
```

Above command results following error:

```
convert.im6: unable to read font `Arial' @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/853.
```

I searched the web and find that many users saw this error, but did not find any solution. Can anyone help?

**NOTE 1:** Arial font is installed on my system:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i arial
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Italic.ttf: Arial:style=Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ariblk.ttf: Arial Black:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf: Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf: Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf: Arial:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbi.ttf: Arial:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Black.ttf: Arial Black:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial_Bold.ttf: Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/ariali.ttf: Arial:style=Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
```

**NOTE 2:**  Changing the case in font name (`arial` instead of `Arial`)does not help.

**NOTE 3:** Using absolute font file path with complete font file name (`filename.fileextension`) removes the error:

```
convert -size 300x50 xc:none -font "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf" -pointsize 20 -gravity center -draw "fill white text 1,1 \"$1\" text 0,0 \"$1\" fill black text -1,-1 \"$1\"" $WATERMARK_FILE
```

Comment: Before posting as an answer: I solved it by using absolute path to the font in question. Not sure why though. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `fc-list  | grep -i arial`. The command you show worked for me with no error. Do you have Arial installed?

Comment: @terdon, on Ubuntu, this is a common issue. Never found an explanation though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm presumably, it's something about the name of the font in the font-cache then. Perhaps it needs lowercase `arial` or the name is slightly different. You also need to have the `msttcorefonts` installed, I think.

Comment: @terdon When I ran into it (was something for Parto:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/552456/gimp-plugin-to-change-ticket-number-and-export-image-automatically) I tried everything: upper/lowercase, also all types of fonts with no luck. On some post (not AU) I ran into the suggestion to use absolute paths. Worked, without the satisfaction of understanding why.

Comment: Hi php, could you mention if it works?

Comment: The information you asked for is added to my question.

Comment: Please move your note #3 to its own answer :)

Answer (score 17):

Arial is not a free font. Its terms of use on open source platforms like Linux and Ubuntu make it
impossible to distribute as part of an installation.  You should
use [one of the free/open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial#Free_alternatives) alternatives
such as Liberation.

You can list the fonts you have with `convert -list font`. Eg:

```
$ convert -list font|grep Liberation-Sans
Font: Liberation-Sans-Bold
Font: Liberation-Sans-Bold-Italic
Font: Liberation-Sans-Italic
Font: Liberation-Sans-Narrow-Bold
Font: Liberation-Sans-Narrow-Bold-Italic
Font: Liberation-Sans-Narrow-Italic
Font: Liberation-Sans-Narrow-Regular
Font: Liberation-Sans-Regular
```

Comment: I can assure you, it has nothing to do with that. All fonts work if absolute paths are used. Did you try?

Comment: Dear meuh, it is not related to font license or copyright. It is just related to font name in my system. Your answer guided me to use `$ convert -list font | grep "Font:" | grep Arial` command and it resulted:
`Font: Arial-Black-Regular
    Font: Arial-Bold
    Font: Arial-Bold-Italic
    Font: Arial-Italic
    Font: Arial-Regular`. Thus I understand that I must use "Arial-Regular" instead of "Arial" as font name. Please update your answer!

Comment: That list is empty

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem with my Macbook today. The cause of that is a simple one.

convert uses only known fonts. All known fonts to convert are listed with this command.

```
convert -list font
```

My desired font was in `~/Library/Fonts`. convert didn't list it.

I followed the instructions from [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696433/why-font-list-is-empty-for-imagemagick) and was capable generating my `type.xml`.

The entry for my font in type.xml

```
<type format="ttf"
  name="MyriadPro"
  fullname="MyriadPro-Regular"
  family="Myriad Pro" 
  glyphs="/Users/vinh/Library/Fonts/myriadpro-regular.ttf"/>
```

I can use the name or the absolute path to generate my image.

```
convert -size 300x50 xc:none -font "MyriadPro" \
  -pointsize 20 -kerning 1 -gravity center \
  -fill black -annotate 0x0+0+0 "mimacom" \
  -fill white -annotate 0x0+2+2 "mimacom" mimacom.png
```